# Dropdown value in angular2

Tags: angular2-routing

I want to display value after selecting dropdown and radio button. I have a dropdown of employee that consists of value 5, 10, 15,20, 25. For that I wrote in component.ts like this:

```
 employees = [{value: 5}, {value: 10}, {value: 15}, {value: 20}, {value: 25} ]
```

and called that in component.html as

```
  <select>
    <option *ngFor='let a of employees'>{{a.value}} </option>
  </select>
```

Now I have a radio button of onemonth, twomonth. like this

```
 <input type="radio" value="month" (click)= "pclick()"> Month
 <input type="radio" value="year" (click)= "pclick()"> Year
```

Now what I want is If I will select number of employee as 5 and radiobutton month it should display value 50, then if I will select dropdown of employee 10 and radio button year it should display value as 120.

```
employee = [{value: "5"}, {value: "10"}, {value: "15"}, {value: "25"}, {value: "75"} ]
employee = {value: " "}
pay= 'monthly'
rupees = 10
amount = 0  

calculateAmount(employee, pay, rupees) {
if (pay == 'Year') {
  this.amount = rupees * 12 * employee
}else if (pay == 'Quarter') {
  this.amount = rupees * 3 * employee
} else {
  this.amount = rupees* employee
}
}
```

Could anyone please help me I am new in angular2. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your template

```
<select [(ngModel)]="employee">
   <option *ngFor='let a of employees' value=a.value>{{a.value}} </option>
</select>
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="monthly">
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="yearly">
<input type="radio" [(ngModel)]="quarterly">
<input type="button" value="Calculate" (click)="calculate()">
```

In your component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'employee',
    templateUrl: './employee.component.html'
})

export class EmployeeComponent{
   private employee:number=0;
   private monthly:any;
   private yearly:any;
   private quarterly:any;
   private rupees:number = 10
   private amount:number = 0
   private pay:string= 'monthly';
   private employees = [{value: "5"}, {value: "10"}, {value: "15"}, {value: "25"}, {value: "75"} ] ; 

   calculateAmount() {
      if (this.yearly.checked) {
         this.amount = this.rupees * 12 * this.employee
      }else if (this.monthly.checked) {
          this.amount = this.rupees * 3 * this.employee
      } else {
          this.amount = this.rupees * this.employee
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want if user will be 10 and month radio button then the value should be 100. similarly if user is 15 and radio button is month then value should be 150 and if user is 15  and radio button is year then value should be 180.

Comment: I didn't get your calculation please add your calculation part and you can place your calculation code inside the if condition easily

Comment: Now see I have added the code above now tell me how to display after selecting a drop down of employee and radio button. in a text box.
<input type= "text">

Comment: <input type= "text" [ngModel]="calculateAmount"> is not giving value.